# I'm getting "the object of type 'MeshRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to acces it" after destroying and instantiating a prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So i have a plumber/pipe game which looks like this:
[Pipe/Plumber game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baogb.png).

When the level is not finished within the time or limited moves the user gets a try again button which restarts the game by destroying the current prefab with all the pipes and instantiates a new prefab of the same level.

Every pipe holds a pipe class, which is also responsible for changing the material of the pipe itself, here are a few examples of what it looks like:
[When level is not finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XeLb.png),
[When level is finished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtYjU.png).

But when the prefab gets destroyed and instatiated to start again, the materials cant be changed like that anymore because i get a error that says: "MissingReferenceException: the object of type 'MeshRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to acces it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object."

In the "Start()" of the script I cache the MeshRenderer of the pipe like this:

```cs
private MeshRenderer _renderer;

private void Start()
{
    _renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
}
```

There a also 4 functions for changing the material of the pipe that make use of this cached component:

```cs
//Changes the material of the pipe to the watered pipe
public void ChangeColor()
{
    _renderer.material = _wateredPipe;
}

//Changes the material of the pipe to the original material
public void RevertToOriginalMaterial()
{
    _renderer.material = _originalMaterial;
}

//Changes the material of the pipe to the red material
public void MakePipeRed()
{
    _renderer.material.color = Color.red;
}

        
//Changes the material of the pipe to the green material
public void MakePipeGreen()
{
    _renderer.material.color = Color.green;
}
```

This is what the script that destroys and instantiates the object looks like, the function ResetPipeGrid() gets called if the button is clicked:

```cs
[SerializeField] private GameObject pipeGridPrefab;
private GameObject _currentPipeGrid;

private void Start()
{
    _currentPipeGrid = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PipeGrid");
}
        
public void ResetPipeGrid()
{
    DestroyGrid();
    InstantiateGrid();
}

private void InstantiateGrid()
{
    _currentPipeGrid = Instantiate(pipeGridPrefab);
}

private void DestroyGrid()
{
    Destroy(_currentPipeGrid);
}
```

After i instantiate the prefab, it throws this exception and it points to these functions/the cached component.

I broke my brains on this problem the past few days but i do know for sure it has something to do with the cached component, i tried to cache the materials but this wasn't the problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.
Please add your code how you destroy and instantiate your GameObjects.
It sounds like are destroying your MeshRenderer but not your component that accesses it.

Comment: @ephb there you go i added that part